# cp command shouldn't fail

Tags: unix, ksh, aix

I am trying to write a piece, where I am trying to do a file swap between ${File} and ${File}.new

Original code was like this -

```
generate ${File}.new
mv ${File} ${File}.backup
mv ${File}.new ${File}
```

It failed for some cases, when at the very same moment the first mv has finished, but second mv has not finished, there can be a request for the ${File}. And that request is denied since the file is not available by that name.  Happens rarely, but nevertheless, happens (happened yesterday for the first time in 6 weeks)

To avoid that, I thought of replacing `mv` with `cp` and therefore, I am trying to build something like this -

```
generate ${File}.new
cp ${File} ${File}.backup
cp ${File}.new ${File}

rm ${File}.new
```

Now, my challenge is that, at the moment when I am writing to ${File}, if there is a  process reading that at that very moment, the copy might fail, saying that it couldnt acquire a lock on the object.

Is my fear of failure true founded ?

I want to tell the program to wait for a few seconds/minutes and then try again, instead of failing.

I am on AIX 6.1 with korn shell.

Answer (score 1):

See if you can get this to work for you.  Make "file" a symbolic link to two other files, file1 and file2.  Use the command "ln -fs file1 file" to create this link.  When somebody opens up "file" the OS will redirect you to "file1"  When you wish to create your backup, run the command "ln -fs file2 file" and now file will be pointing to file2.  You can then do anything you wish to do on file1.  Reverse the process to go back to file1.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a hard link to do the backup part:

```
generate ${File}.new
ln -f ${File} ${File}.backup
mv ${File}.new ${File}
```

After `ln`, there'll be two filenames for the old file. After `mv`, only the `.backup` filename will refer to the old file, `${File}` will refer to the new file.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about your system but mine says `cp -f` will remove the file if it can't immediately overwrite it. (There are also options for automatically backing the file up, but check the manual for your system.)

Comment: I cant afford to remove the file before overwriting... in that case, it would fail the process which has currently locked the file.